# What would I gain by upgrading a norco vfr 2 hybrid bike group set to tiagra or 105 shimano group set

Tags: shimano, upgrades, groupsets

What would I gain by upgrading a norco vfr 2 hybrid bike group set from alivio 9*3 speed to a tiagra or 105 shimano group set? Are there any things to consider or look out for?

Comment: Your original question was a bit broad as well as a shopping question, which isn't well suited to this stackexchange. I modified it to make it fit better, but feel free to roll back my edits if they match your intent.

Comment: A lighter wallet? More seriously, if you have integrated levers and V-brakes, you'd need travel agents or new brakes as well. Why are you intent to upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

Things to Gain:

1. Higher quality groupset
2. Headache
3. Frustration
4. Thinner wallet

It is not really a good idea for this type of bike to consider trying to evolve itself into another type with the components your suggesting

Reasons:

1. The Norco VFR 2 Hybrid has the Norco 25mm Riser and handlebars which are not compatible with Tiagra or 105 shifters.
2. Tiagra and 105 are both STI (Shimano Total Integration), This means that they are not designed to fit this bike handlebar style and are designed for drop style handlebars
3. Trying to keep your original shifters will probably not work as the indexing will not mesh. Although there have been some reports of users getting lucky mismatching shifter and derailleur models, it is generally not a good idea and leads to frustration and ending up with brand new components you spent good money on that just don't work.
4. Brakes are another story. Trying to match your existing levers with tiagra or 105 calipers will most likely lead to more frustration as chances are, you will never get them adjusted perfectly to your liking and the original brakes may feel more natural and function better.
5. 105 does not come in 9 speed so you will be limited to Tiagra.
6. You can not upgrade to a 10 speed group without changing out your rear hub which would mean a new wheel or wheel-set.
7. You mentioned 9/3 drivetrain. I imagine that means a triple front crank which is not compatible with tiagra or 105 and would require a crank replacement.

Comment: There are Tiagra flat bar shifters in 9 speed. But they expect a road FD in the front.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies - I am now thinking that I may better off to move a new bike that is a road bike with better gear such Shimano 105 group set rather than trying to make the Norco into something it is going to be more trouble than it is worth

Comment: Oh yeh Tiagra ones. I forgot about those.